# mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string,

Tags: php, mysql

I have used `mysql_real_escape_string` but it will give following error:

> warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/example/infostud.php on line 16
>   line 16

```
$department=mysql_real_escape_string(['department']);
```

Comment: Wrapping a string in `[]` makes it an array containing that string value, not simply a string anymore.... so fix it

Comment: And then stop using the old MySQL extension, and move onto using a 21st century database interface like MySQLi or PDO

Comment: use mysqli or PDO instead of MYSQL

Comment: $department=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['department']);    And indeed, switch to PDO or MySQLi

Answer (score 0):

hi if you have on your page html or form to send the values this
page.html

```
<html>
<head><title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<hr>
<form action="page_to_process.php" method="post">
name:<br>
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" size=50>
<br>addres:<br>
<input name="addres" id="addres" type="text"size=50>
<br>phone:<br>
<input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" size=50>
<br>
<p>
  <input type="submit"  value="send" id="send" name="send">
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

then you on the page that you need receive the values make some one this:

page_to_process.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send']))
{   
$name   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$addres = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['addres']);
$phone  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
}
```

then you have the values on $name , $addres, $phone

for this you have some one methods post, get i prefer post

try and good luck...!!!